# Wordpress 3.9 - 4.1 and qTranslate issue

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

I have found a bug after the upgrading the Wordpress to the last version of the software 3.9.

I get this error:

> Thu Apr 17 17:21:52 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Catchable
>   fatal error:  Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string
>   in /wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_core.php on line 455,
>   referer: http://www.mywebsite.com/

Why do this happen?

Comment: What's the code on the line mentioned? If you don't have any luck on here, try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which might suite better for any wordpress related dev question.

Comment: Why not file a bug with the author of the plugin? It's obvious that the issue is with plugin not working with 3.9. Perhaps wait for a fix from them?

Comment: @DanFromGermany I don't know the website wordpress.stackexchange.com ... however thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Solved!!

You have to remove the "`$before`." in `qtranslate_core.php` file from the last line, qtranslate works here with `WP 3.9` !

so the result must be:

```
return strftime($format, $date).$after;
```

We will wait the `qTranslate` upgrade!

thanks

Comment: On my plugin, it was the last line of the `qtrans_strftime` function.

Comment: return $before.strftime($format, $date).$after; => return strftime($format, $date).$after;

Comment: Works with 4.1.1 too.

Comment: Nice. Works with 4.4.1 too.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add my 2 cents after investigating this issue myself. I don't like to ever hack the core of WP or the plugins. When I got the error indicated by the author of this thread, I fixed it by going into `Settings -> Languages` and clicking the `Advanced Settings` tab.

Under the `Date / Time Conversion` section it was set to the first option `Use emulated date function.` I changed it to `Use strftime instead of date.` and voila, no more error and no hacking the core!

Report back if this worked for you or if you had any issues.

Wordpress: v3.9.1
qTranslate: v2.5.39

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I tried all the options but had to resort to the hack

Comment: Interesting! For science, how are you calling the date in the offending page? I only got this bug when displaying the date. I'm using `<?php print get_the_date(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for great solution, this works superb in my case. page edit was not working.

Comment: I am also unable to edit permalinks on edit page because of this. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

For me (WP 4.1.1, qTranslate 2.5.39) the following helped:

1. From the dashboard, go to Plugins > qTranslate > Settings
2. Click the "Advanced Settings" link
3. In the "Date / Time Conversion" settings group select "Use strftime instead of date and replace formats with the predefined formats for each language." (was set to "Use strftime instead of date").

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately all above didn't work for me, but I [found](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/akirk/10979790/raw/3b2b37b399a82dc82723fb6b8e703c1d981b26f9/qtranslate_core.php.diff) [another solution](https://alexander.kirk.at/2014/04/17/fix-qtranslate-with-wordpress-3-9/), which helped me solve that issue:

in file **qtranslate_core.php** you must change this line

```
function qtrans_dateFromPostForCurrentLanguage($old_date, $format ='', $before = '', $after = '') {
```

to

```
function qtrans_dateFromPostForCurrentLanguage($old_date, $format ='') {
```

and this line

```
return qtrans_strftime(qtrans_convertDateFormat($format), mysql2date('U',$post->post_date), $old_date, $before, $after);
```

to

```
return qtrans_strftime(qtrans_convertDateFormat($format), mysql2date('U',$post->post_date), $old_date);
```